# Two queries work on their own, but results become invalid when I add OR

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables which contain information about projects and their advancement milestones known as steps.

Project Table.

```
+----------+----------+------------+------------+
|idproject | idclient | dateStart  |  dateEnd   |
+----------+----------+------------+------------+
|        1 |      321 | 2011-08-01 | NULL       |
|        2 |      321 | 2012-05-01 | 2012-07-23 |
|        3 |      345 | 2011-11-01 | NULL       |
+----------+----------+------------+------------+
```

ProjectSteps table

```
+---------+----------+------------+------------+
| idStep  |idProject |  dateStart |  dateEnd   |
+---------+----------+------------+------------+
|       1 |        1 | 2011-07-01 | 2011-09-01 |
|       1 |        2 | 2012-05-01 | 2012-05-10 |
|       1 |        3 | 2011-11-01 | 2012-01-20 |
|       2 |        1 | 2011-09-02 | 2011-11-30 |
|       2 |        2 | 2012-05-11 | 2019-01-01 |
|       2 |        3 | 2012-01-21 | 2012-04-01 |
|       3 |        1 | 2011-12-01 | 2012-07-07 |
|       3 |        2 | 2012-06-02 | 2012-07-01 |
|       3 |        3 | 2012-04-02 | NULL       |
|       4 |        1 | 2012-07-08 | NULL       |
|       4 |        2 | 2012-07-01 | 2012-07-21 |
|       5 |        2 | 2012-07-22 | 2012-07-23 |
+---------+----------+------------+------------+
```

I need to validate that each step has been done within the start/end dates of their project.

For example Step 1 of project 1 is invalid, as it starts before the project start, and Step 2 of project 2 is also invalid, because it ends after the project ends.

These two queries work separately:

This one checks the start date of each step against the project start/end dates and only displays invalid ones, so Project 1 step 1:

```sql
SELECT e.idProject, p.dateStart, p.dateEnd, e.idStep, e.dateStart, e.dateEnd
FROM projectSteps e, project p
WHERE e.idProject = p.idProject
AND e.dateStart NOT BETWEEN (SELECT p2.dateStart
                             from project p2
                             WHERE p2.idProject = p.idProject)
                             AND
                            (SELECT p3.dateEnd
                             FROM project p3
                             WHERE p3.idProject = p.idProject);
```

Same, but for Ending dates, will output Project 2 step 2:

```sql
SELECT e.idProject, p.dateStart, p.dateEnd, e.idStep, e.dateStart, e.dateEnd
FROM projectSteps e, project p
WHERE e.idProject = p.idProject
AND e.dateEnd NOT BETWEEN (SELECT p4.dateStart
                           from project p4
                           WHERE p4.idProject = p.idProject)
                           AND
                          (SELECT p5.dateEnd
                           FROM project p5
                           WHERE p5.idProject = p.idProject);
```

However if I try to combine both with OR like this:

```sql
SELECT e.idProject, p.dateStart, p.dateEnd, e.idStep, e.dateStart, e.dateEnd
FROM projectSteps e, project p
WHERE e.idProject = p.idProject
AND e.dateStart NOT BETWEEN (SELECT p2.dateStart
                             from project p2
                             WHERE p2.idProject = p.idProject)
                             AND
                            (SELECT p3.dateEnd
                             FROM project p3
                             WHERE p3.idProject = p.idProject)
OR e.dateEnd NOT BETWEEN (SELECT p4.dateStart
                          from project p4
                          WHERE p4.idProject = p.idProject)
                          AND
                         (SELECT p5.dateEnd
                          FROM project p5
                          WHERE p5.idProject = p.idProject);
```

I end up with this:

```
+----------+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+
|idProject | dateStart  |  dateEnd   | idStep  | dateStart  | dateEnd    |
+----------+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+
|        1 | 2011-08-01 | NULL       |       1 | 2011-07-01 | 2011-09-01 |
|        1 | 2012-05-01 | 2012-07-23 |       1 | 2011-07-01 | 2011-09-01 |
|        1 | 2011-11-01 | NULL       |       1 | 2011-07-01 | 2011-09-01 |
|        3 | 2012-05-01 | 2012-07-23 |       1 | 2011-11-01 | 2012-01-20 |
|        1 | 2012-05-01 | 2012-07-23 |       2 | 2011-09-02 | 2011-11-30 |
|        2 | 2012-05-01 | 2012-07-23 |       2 | 2012-05-11 | 2019-01-01 |
|        3 | 2012-05-01 | 2012-07-23 |       2 | 2012-01-21 | 2012-04-01 |
+----------+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I was expecting this:

```
+----------+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+
|idProject | dateStart  |  dateEnd   | idStep  | dateStart  | dateEnd    |
+----------+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+
|        1 | 2011-08-01 | NULL       |       1 | 2011-07-01 | 2011-09-01 |
|        2 | 2012-05-01 | 2012-07-23 |       2 | 2012-05-11 | 2019-01-01 |
+----------+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: you need to enclose the two in braces. `AND (...) OR (...)`

Comment: Actually, this worked : AND ((...) OR (...)).

Thanks you for sending me down the right path.

Comment: good to know it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end after some experimentation it really was a bracketing problem.

Thanks for the suggestions everyone.

This works :

```
SELECT e.idProject, p.dateStart, p.dateEnd, e.idStep, e.dateStart, e.dateEnd
FROM projectSteps e, project p
WHERE e.idProject = p.idProject
AND (e.dateStart NOT BETWEEN (SELECT p2.dateStart
                             from project p2
                             WHERE p2.idProject = p.idProject)
                             AND
                            (SELECT p3.dateEnd
                             FROM project p3
                             WHERE p3.idProject = p.idProject)
OR e.dateEnd NOT BETWEEN (SELECT p4.dateStart
                          from project p4
                          WHERE p4.idProject = p.idProject)
                          AND
                         (SELECT p5.dateEnd
                          FROM project p5
                          WHERE p5.idProject = p.idProject));
```

So the correct structure is : AND ((...) OR (...))

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `AND` and `OR` for the whole conditions, which means you have to put them in brackets. In your case, the `AND` (`OR`) influences only `e.dateStart`

```
SELECT e.idProject, p.dateStart, p.dateEnd, e.idStep, e.dateStart, e.dateEnd
FROM projectSteps e, project p
WHERE e.idProject = p.idProject
AND (e.dateStart NOT BETWEEN (SELECT p2.dateStart
                             from project p2
                             WHERE p2.idProject = p.idProject)
                             AND
                            (SELECT p3.dateEnd
                             FROM project p3
                             WHERE p3.idProject = p.idProject))
OR (e.dateEnd NOT BETWEEN (SELECT p4.dateStart
                          from project p4
                          WHERE p4.idProject = p.idProject)
                          AND
                         (SELECT p5.dateEnd
                          FROM project p5
                          WHERE p5.idProject = p.idProject));
```

Comment: will you mind to add something as an explanation on how this should solve the issue? Without an explanation it is just a comment to the question.